# Ad-Hoc distribution with Team Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

According to the Apple docs, one must create and use a distribution certificate and a distribution profile for distributing an app ad-hoc.

> "To use ad hoc distribution, create a distribution provisioning profile specifying Ad Hoc as the distribution method and include a list of up to 100 devices authorized to run the app."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Well, this is not neccessary i have found out. You could easily distribute an app ad-hoc with just the developer certificate and the team provisioning profile. 
Is it a bad idea to use the team prov. profile and just a developer certificate?

Why should i create an ad-hoc dist. profile if it's more easy to just use the team prov. profile?

Comment: Correct. It's possible (even via TestFlight for example) to distribute the IPA with a provisioning certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Distribution builds have the property that cannot be debugged (that's what the `get-task-allow` property in the entitlements plist is for). This means that others cannot attach a debugger to your code and achieve undesirable results.

Distribution builds are required if you want to allow remote users to download the application via an App Store (Apple's or enterprise).

Comment: Yes, so why doesn't Apple mention that you don't necessarily need a distribution certificate? I'm just curious find out if there is another good reason Apple don't mention this.

Comment: You do need it if you're planning on releasing your application to more than 100 people. You can only add 100 names to your provisioning profile - the App Store release is unlimited.